# Understanding gensim Word2Vec most_similar results for 3 words

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I construct sentences using 3 words "1", "2", "3", in different ways, and observe that the word vectors are unchanged for each of these words.

Following are the different sentences

Type 1: [["1", "2"], ["1", "3"]]

Type 2: [["1", "2", "3"]]

Type 3: [["1", "2"], ["3"]]

I am training `Word2Vec` model as follows

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences,min_count=1,size=2)
print (model.wv.most_similar("1"))
print (model.wv.most_similar("2"))
print (model.wv.most_similar("3"))
print (model.wv['1'])
print (model.wv['2'])
print (model.wv['3'])
```

And results are same on changing the sentence type

```
[('3', 0.5377859473228455), ('2', -0.5831003785133362)]
[('1', -0.5831003189086914), ('3', -0.9985027313232422)]
[('1', 0.5377858281135559), ('2', -0.9985026717185974)]
[-0.24893647 -0.24495095]
[ 0.19231372 -0.03319569]
[-0.22207274  0.05098101]
```

Also when I change word "1" to suppose "101", the result changes

```
[('3', 0.5407046675682068), ('2', -0.5859125256538391)]
[('101', -0.5859125256538391), ('3', -0.9985027313232422)]
[('101', 0.540704607963562), ('2', -0.9985026717185974)]
[-0.05898098 -0.0576357 ]
[ 0.19231372 -0.03319569]
[-0.22207274  0.05098101]
```

I wanted to know

1. Why the results didn't change when I changed the sentences?
2. Why results changed when I just updated the value?

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec as an algorithm requires large, varied datasets to train word-vectors into meaningful arrangements.

You won't get sensible results, or learn much about the algorithm's behavior or benefits, with toy-sized contrived training data.

Also note:

- `Word2Vec` uses random initialization and random-sampling as part of its process, so even a run on the exact same data can have different results from run-to-run. However, with a realistic amount and variety of data, each run should result in a model that's about-as-useful as any other run (even though many of the exact positions/relative-rankings may vary).
- A nested list-of-lists, like your 1st "sentence" (`[["1", "2"], ["1", "3"]]`), isn't valid training input for `Word2Vec`. Each "sentence" should be a simple list of string-tokens (words).

I suggest you experiment with true natural-language training data, with the quantity of words, and variety of contrasting usages, that appear in real texts. I recommend training data that has at least a few thousand unique words where each word has 5 or more diverse usage examples.

There's actually a small such corpus bundled inside gensim, as an aid to its self-testing code and intro tutorials. It's called the 'Lee Corpus', and is an old research corpus of about 300 short news articles of a couple hundred words each. You can see an example of its use at the "Training Your Own Model" section of the gensim Word2Vec tutorial:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#training-your-own-model

Comment: [["my", "name", "is", "harry"], ["Your", "name", "is", "Ron"]] is a valid sentence list? similarly [["1", "2"], ["1", "3"]] is also a valid list right? Also agreed that it requires large data set. But in this case shouldn't "1" be similar to both "2" and "3" equally?

Comment: Yes, `[["1", "2"], ["1", "3"]]` would be valid as the sequence-of-all-examples (`sentences`). but not as a single sentence – I didn't realize all of your "Type 1", "Type 2", etc examples where alternate `sentences`.

Comment: With such a tiny contrived dataset, nothing can really be said about what "should" or "shouldn't" be the case with the final results. In particular, even words that, in your corpus, had exactly identical usage contexts wouldn't necessarily wind up in the same place, or be "equally" similar to other reference words, because of the inherent randomness in the initialization and training of the model. You should only expect meaningful results that match reasoned expectations with larger, varied training data. (And even there, no precise equalities, just rough correlations.)